# Using Salesforce AMPscript functions in Marketing Cloud - Limitations

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

We haven't found the answer for this in the documentation so perhaps someone here can help us. We would like to know if using Salesforce AMPScript functions such `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` counts towrads MC or SF API limits? i.e Does each use of those functions count as an API request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation about MC Connect and authentication between clouds:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_authentication.htm&type=0

Quote from above documentation:
"Connected App Authentication is a secure authentication mechanism used by Marketing Cloud Connect. It removes the need to manage any Sales or Service Cloud user passwords in Marketing Cloud. It removes SOAP and REST API limits for Marketing Cloud Connect. Connected App Authentication does not lift BULK API limits. API calls made into the Marketing Cloud do not count against your daily limit."

If you are running API calls back and forth from Marketing Cloud to Sales Cloud outside either Apex or AMPscript, these are the limits you should expect:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

See the below documentation regarding temporarily/permanently increasing your organization's API limit:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315571&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for the detailed answer. So just to be sure - theoretically there is no limit for how many time Salesforce AMPscript functions can be used for both parties (SF and MC)? Thanks

Comment: Yes Barak you are right.